# Error in resolving server side tag

Tags: asp.net

Invalid expression term '<'

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" 
            Width="180px" TextMode="Password" 
            OnTextChanged="CheckPasswordStrength(<%= txtPassword.ClientID.ToString() %>,<%= lblMessage.ClientID.ToString() %>)"/>
```

If i writes this code like the following then error occurs An unhandled exception has occured. Server tags cannot contain <% %> constructs

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" 
                Width="180px" TextMode="Password" 
                OnTextChanged="CheckPasswordStrength("<%= txtPassword.ClientID.ToString() %>","<%= lblMessage.ClientID.ToString() %>")"/>
```

When I m using this code at .cs file then every thing is working fine.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPassword.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "PasswordCheck("+txtPassword.ClientID.ToString()+")");
        txtPrimaryEmail.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "EmailChecker("+txtPrimaryEmail.ClientID.ToString()+")");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things going on with this.. You can't include parameters in your server-side event, and you can't use <%= in a server control.

Are you meaning to fire a JavaScript event?

If you're meaning to fire a JavaScript event, do one of three things:

1) Use a databinding expression (<%# Control.ClientID %>) - This requires that somewhere within the life-cycle DataBind() is being called on your control.

2) Assign the event in the code-behind, using Control.Attributes.Add("javascriptevent", "DoStuff(x, y)")

3) You can use <%= %> in your client script, e.g.

```
function MyJavaScriptEventHandler()
{
   var textbox = document.getElementById('<%= MyASPTextBox.ClientID %>');
   alert(textbox.value);
}
```

Comment: thx for help, 1 question. If i m using external js file then does this method work

Comment: The third method won't work for an external file. The 1st and 2nd would. I'd recommend sticking with how you're doing it now, assigning it to the attributes collection in code-behind.

Comment: You won't be able to do it if it's in an external js file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can include parameters in a Server Event.  You will need to reference those controls from the Code-Behind.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.  Server controls cannot contain `<%` (evaluation for those tags occurs after the server controls - so those tags are considered part of the server control and it fails parsing).

You might want to add the ontextchanged attribute in your code-behind.  You could also use JavaScript.