# How do I display string from code behind in page

Tags: asp.net, variables, user-interface, code-behind

I'm trying to display a public string 'TrialExtensionLengthDays' that's declared in my code behind, in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Button ID="ExtendTrialButton" runat="server" Text="Extend Trial" CssClass="actionButton extendTrialButton"  title="Extend Trial by <%=TrialExtensionLengthDays%> days" OnClientClick="confirm('Extend the Customer Demo by <%=TrialExtensionLengthDays%> days?')"/>
```

Here's the relevant part of the code behind:

```
Public Class EditTrialCustomer
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Public TrialExtensionLengthDays As String

Protected Sub Page_OnPreInit()
    TrialExtensionLengthDays = (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TrialExtensionLengthDays"))
End Sub
```

Why's it not working?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Duplicate question: See "Error in resolving server side tag"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947777/error-in-resolving-server-side-tag J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tooltip.aspx) property instead of title.

Use code behind in Page Load to set this properties:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExtendTrialButton.ToolTip = "Extend Trial by " + TrialExtensionLengthDays + " days";
        ExtendTrialButton.OnClientClick = "confirm('Extend the Customer Demo by" + TrialExtensionLengthDays + " days?')";
    }
```

and your asp page just:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="actionButton extendTrialButton" ID="ExtendTrialButton"  runat="server" Text="Extend Trial"  />
```

Comment: Before I give you an upvote, can I recommend that you demonstrate the code for the asker?

Comment: No difference, but good suggestion thanks.  I'm just getting  <%=TrialExtensionLengthDays %> shown on the page

Comment: Where specifically are you getting that? you didn't show us any page code

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring

> TrialExtensionLengthDays StringBuilder rather than String